# Flutter: Banner Ad Overlapping The Main Screen

Tags: dart, admob, flutter

I am doing a Flutter app and managed to show the AdMob banner ad, however the ad overlaps the bottom of my app's main screen:

[image]

By following [this article](http://cogitas.net/show-firebase-admob-banner-ad-in-flutter/), I managed to make the app screen's bottom properly displayed, but the persistentFooterButtons is sacrificed, which I think is not an ideal solution.
[image]

I am thinking about putting the Scaffold object and a fixed height area into a column that is contained by a Center object, something similar to the following:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return new Center(
      child: new Column (
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          new Expanded (
              child:  _getScaffold(),
          ),
          new Expanded (
              child: new Container(height: 50.0,)
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

But in this way I get the exception "*A RenderFlex overflowed by 228 pixels on the bottom*":

[image]

Anybody can show me how to build such layout? I want every component of my scaffold properly displayed, with a fixed height dummy footer that is ok to be overlapped by the Admob's banner ad.

Any help is much welcome.

Jimmy

Comment: can you provide a runnable code ? This code snippet doesn't help at all.

Comment: @Darky Sorry because the code of my Scaffold object is quite messy, for simplicity I just posted the code of the build method; maybe I post back the full class later.

Answer (score 12):

Also we can add some trick like bottomNavigationBar under the Scaffold

```
bottomNavigationBar: Container(
    height: 50.0,
    color: Colors.white,
  ),
```

This will take floating button up.

Comment: This should be marked as the answer as the main issue observed was that ads were overlapping main screen in bottom and this does the job perfectly

Comment: this is the perfect answer!

Comment: I think the answer could be improved by replacing `50.0` with `MediaQuery.of(context).padding.bottom` this way the height would be calculated dynamically and in my case the value was `48.0`.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question well, I think you want to have your ad shown from the bottom while using a FAB. I think using a `Stack` widget here is a good solution, I created this example in a rush but should be enough to show you what I mean:

[image]

```
class AdBar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AdBarState createState() => new _AdBarState();
}

class _AdBarState extends State<AdBar> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(),
        body: new ListView(
          children: new List.generate(50, (int index) {
            return new Text("widgets$index");
          }),
        ),
        persistentFooterButtons:

        <Widget>[
          new Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Container (
                color: Colors.transparent,
                child: new Material(
                  color: Colors.cyanAccent,
                  child: new InkWell(
                    onTap: () {

                    },
                    child: new Container(
                      //color: Colors.cyanAccent,
                      width: MediaQuery
                          .of(context)
                          .size
                          .width * 0.90,
                      height: MediaQuery
                          .of(context)
                          .size
                          .height * 0.25,
                    ),
                  ),),),
              new Positioned(
                  right: 0.0,
                  child: new FloatingActionButton(
                      onPressed: () {}, child: new Icon(Icons.fastfood)))
            ],
          )
        ]

    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I doupt he's expecting the floating button to be over the ad. That would be so evil.

Comment: Thanks aziza for your help but Darky is right, maybe I just didn't make it clear.

I want the banner ad positioned below my Scaffold, making the floating button over the ad is not what I expect.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I got it:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

 return new Center(
   child: new Column (
     crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
     mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
     children: <Widget>[
       new Expanded (
          child: _getScaffold(),
       ),
       new Container(height: 50.0,
            child: new Placeholder(color:Colors.blue))
      ],
    ),
  );
 }
```

The trick is Expanded here is for the Scaffold only, but for the dummy footer just a fixed height Container is required. Now I can display everything available from the Scaffold object.

Layout building of Flutter sometimes really confuses me...

Comment: Why do you have a Center widget ?

Comment: @Darky: Just tested, you are right the outer Center widget is redundant.

Comment: At the same time, `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min` is useless too